# Show and hide Grid Column

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

How to change the grid column value basend on the certain value in another column of that record (row).

I have two column **step1_formula** and **step2_formula** if user selected step2 formula from UI form i need to show the content of both column in grid but if user select only step1_formula I need to show **Not Applicable** in the column **step2_formula** on that record (row )

Comment: You can display different amount of rows per page in Magento Dashboard. Is this applied to rows on the current page or all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show hide ui component grid column by this way in ui component.

```
Add a custom class in your column

    <column name="step1_formula" class="vendor\module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\FormulaGridActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Step1 Formula </item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Paste the following code here

> vendor\module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\FormulaGridActions

```
<?php

namespace vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;


class FormulaGridActions extends Column
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                if($item['result_steps'] == 0)
                {
                    $item['step2_formula'] = ""; 
                    // $item['step1_formula'] = $item['result_color_grams'].''.; 
                }

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

 */
    public function prepare()
    {
       if ($condition) { // Your condition goes here
       $status = true;
        }
          $this->_data['config']['componentDisabled'] = true; // for removing the column
          parent::prepare();
    }


}
```